# NEAR dev-deploy fails with Error: Can not sign transactions no matching key pair found

Tags: nearprotocol, near

Using a freshly created `create-near-app` I am trying to `dev-deploy` and getting this error:

```
Starting deployment. Account id: dev-1635099366550-3101206, node: https://rpc.testnet.near.org, helper: https://helper.testnet.near.org, file: out/main.wasm
An error occured
Error: Can not sign transactions for account dev-1635099366550-3101206 on network testnet, no matching key pair found in InMemorySigner(MergeKeyStore(UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore(/Users/<username>/.near-credentials), UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore(/Users/<username>/Documents/Projects/new_test_app/neardev))).
```

I'm unsure what's causing it or what needs to be done to resolve it. I've checked the `/Users/<username>/.near-credentials` credentials directory and there is a `.json` file containing credentials. I tried `near clean` & rebuilding, ensured I had done `near login` even tried with `sudo` thinking it might be a permissions error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a reason for the "why" behind this happening, but eventually I tried deleting the `dev-1635099366550-3101206.json` file in `/Users/<username>/.near-credentials` (the first dev account it created) and then re-ran `near dev-deploy`.

This created a new dev account and seemed to work fine. Re-running `near dev-deploy` after that also seemed to work fine, redeploying the contract to the same account.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I tried to open the web on another web browser, the problem disappeared.

[UPDATE]
I clean the browser local storage and import the wallet again, everything works fine.
[image: Local storage value]

Answer (score 0):

Use NEAR connected account interface instead.
You can read more at here : https://near.github.io/near-api-js/classes/walletaccount.connectedwalletaccount.html